# Bootstrap 4 breadcrumb interrupting tabbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm having issues with Bootstrap 4 breadcrumbs "interrupting" the tab-bar dividing line (see https://www.codeply.com/go/ga2O7RQhty)

I've tried playing around with margins, padding etc on the the breadcrumb, but no combination works leaving the breadcrumb looking like it should and not interrupting/breaking the tab-bar line.

[image: The 'red line' is what I'm trying to make appear. I.E A full diving line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearfix` on the page-header...

```
   <div class="page-header clearfix">
      <div class="float-right btn-toolbar">
         <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Audio Library</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
      <h1>
         Audio Library                                  
      </h1>
   </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/sPTmNxG6MJ

This allows the floated btn-toolbar to clear to the next visual row.